# Update parent size

Tags: java, layout, swt

I have a function that should update the size of all parents of a `Composite` when children are added to it, but it isn't working. Here is my code:

```
private void increaseSize(Composite child, Composite parent) {
    parent.layout();
    Rectangle childPosition = child.getBounds();
    Rectangle parentPosition = parent.getBounds();
    int parentY = parent.toDisplay(parentPosition.width, parentPosition.height).y;
    int childY = child.toDisplay(childPosition.width, childPosition.height).y;
    if (childY > parentY) {
        int heightDifference = childY - parentY;
        parent.setSize(parentPosition.width, parentPosition.height + heightDifference + 5);
        System.out.println("parent y: " + parentY + ", child y: " + childY);
    } else {
        return;
    }
    parent.layout();
    parent.setVisible(true);
    if (!(parent instanceof Shell)) {
        increaseSize(parent, parent.getParent());
    }

}
```

If I remove the line in the `if`-statement (`increaseSize(parent, parent.getParent());`) it works just fine for one parent Composite.

Anyone who knows what would make this work?

More code
main:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();

    Shell shell = new Shell (display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
    shell.setSize(200,100);

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Click here to add Composite");

    GridData selectionData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    final CustomComposite selection = new CustomComposite(shell, SWT.BORDER, selectionData);



    button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent selectionEvent) {
            selection.addSelected("I'm added");
        }

        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent selectionEvent) {

        }
    });
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    display.dispose ();
}
```

}

CustomComposite:

```
public class CustomComposite extends Composite{
private GridData layoutData;

public CustomComposite (Composite parent, int style, GridData layoutData) {

    super(parent,style);
    setLayout(new RowLayout());

    setLayoutData(layoutData);
    layoutData.exclude = true;
    this.layoutData = layoutData;

}

public void addSelected(String displayName) {
    SelectedComposite item = new SelectedComposite(this, SWT.BORDER, displayName);
    if (layoutData.exclude == true) {
        layoutData.exclude = false;
        getParent().layout();
    }
    increaseSize(item, this);
    getShell().layout(true, true);
}

private void increaseSize(Composite child, Composite parent) {
    parent.layout();
    Rectangle childPosition = child.getBounds();
    Rectangle parentPosition = parent.getBounds();
    int parentY = parent.toDisplay(parentPosition.width, parentPosition.height).y;
    int childY = child.toDisplay(childPosition.width, childPosition.height).y;
    if (childY > parentY) {
        int heightDifference = childY - parentY;
        parent.setSize(parentPosition.width, parentPosition.height + heightDifference + 5);
    } else {
        return;
    }
    parent.setVisible(true);
    if (!(parent instanceof Shell)) {
        increaseSize(parent, parent.getParent());
    }

}


class SelectedComposite extends Composite{

    private Label label = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);

    public SelectedComposite (Composite parent, int style, String displayName) {
        super(parent, style);
        setLayout(new FillLayout());
        label.setText(displayName);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using any layouts at all?

Comment: Yes I do use different layouts for different composites, mainly gridlayout but for the "first" parent I use rowlayout

Comment: Then why do you need to resize things at all? The layout should take care of that for you.

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't worked for me. Does it matter if I use FillLayout as well?

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the issue? It's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing how you create your widgets and layouts. Usually a `layout(true, true)` on the root element (e.g. the `Shell`) should be enough...

Comment: Tried to find a solution to your problem, but failed. However, I think it's caused by the fact that you're using a `RowLayout` for `CustomComposite`. With a `RowLayout`, `computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT)` will compute its size without wrapping. Not sure how to get the "wrapped size" of it though...

Comment: Thanks for trying, it's appreciated :)